# How to access Docker (with Spark) file systems

Tags: docker

Suppose I am running CentOS. I installed docker, then run the image.

Suppose I use this image:

https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/pyspark-notebook

Then I run

docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 jupyter/pyspark-notebook

Now, I can open the browser with `localhost:8088` and I can create a new Jupyter notebook, type code and run, etc.

However, how can I access the file I created and, for example, commit it to github. Furthermore, if I already have some code on github, how can I pull this code and access these code from docker?

Thank you very much,

Comment: Which stack are you using?

Comment: I use docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 jupyter/pyspark-notebook. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mount the volume

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 -v /opt/pyspark-notebook:/home/jovyan jupyter/pyspark-notebook
```

You should have just executed `!pwd` in the a new notebook and found which folder it was storing the work in. And then mounted that as a volume. When you run it like above the files would be available on your host in `/opt/pyspark-notebook`